# Sending all files into folder with the same name

Tags: linux, command

Let's say we have tens of files in one folder with no pattern. I want to send whole files into the folder with the same name.

Current file structure:

```
 test1234.js
 new-york.php
 foo.cs
```

My aim:

```
 test1234/test1234.js
 new-york/new-york.php
 foo/foo.cs
```

Is it possible to do this with one single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you consider a single command. It can be done with a simple loop:

```
for FILE in *; do
    if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then 
        mkdir -p "${FILE%.*}"
        mv "$FILE" "${FILE%.*}"
    fi
done
```